# deserialize xml string to object

Tags: c#

i wrote this method in order to convert a xml string into the object:

```
private object Deserializer(Type type)
{
    object instance = null;
    try
    {
        XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(type);
        using (StringReader stringreader = new StringReader(somestring))
        {
            instance = (type)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(stringreader);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }

    return instance;
}
```

but here:

```
instance = (type)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(stringreader);
```

this error shows up:
The type or namespace name 'type' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
how can i fix it?

Comment: The compiler tells you already what is wrong: The type `type` you are casting your instance to, does not exist. Are you sure you are using the correct cast?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You canno't cast to "type" you need to specify the exact type like this (for string):

```
(string)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(stringreader);
```

Maybe consider using generic function like this:

```
private T Deserializer<T>()
{
    T instance = null;
    try
    {
        var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        using (var stringreader = new StringReader(somestring))
        {
            instance = (T)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(stringreader);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }

    return instance;
}
```

and than call the function like this:

```
var instance = xmlSerializer.Deserialize<SomeType>();
```

if you want to specify the type only in runtime you can use:

```
instance = Convert.ChangeType(xmlSerializer.Deserialize(stringreader), type);
```

Comment: The try block is useless, you need a string parameter, the T variable is useless.

Answer (score 3):

But what is a  Type is class  that u made or what ?

Maybe u want do to :

```
private object Deserializer<T>(T type)
```

Edit Try this :

```
private static T LoadData<T>() where T : new ()
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(@_path))
        {
            var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            return (T) xmlSerializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }

    }
```

Comment: `Type` is most probably `System.Type`. And I think your solution would be better if it returned `T` instead of `object`.

Comment: Y my bad i try to write it to fast. I edited my comment